# Eclipse edits and saves don't make changes to running program - powercut

Tags: java, eclipse

So I was busy writing away in eclipse when there was a power cut. Luckily I had been saving regularly and so when I got back on I still had all my work.

However after writing a few lines and running it and spending a while trying to figure out why it wasn't working I realized that whatever I wrote didn't change what ran. I could even comment out bits of code OR EVEN the entire program OR EVEN YET DELETE LINES OF CODE, yet it still runs as if the same code was there from before the power cut. In the file menu all the save features are grayed out, yet if I control S and restart my pc or restart eclipse then it has made changes to the code and saved however the new code has made no effect on anything and still runs as before.

Has anyone else experienced this?

Has eclipse got some auto save feature for problems such as power cuts in order to prevent work less?

Has this put eclipse in a special mode that I can exit back to the normal mode?

Comment: build issue? did you clean... build? Try checking "Build Automatically" option in Project menu.

Comment: There seems to be a discrepancy between your actual code and the one you're running. If the code runs as BEFORE the power cut, it's because the build you're running was built by compiling your previous code. As for the code loss, seems like eclipse might have been starving for memory and the saving operation got neglected... tough this is highly unlikely.

Comment: Build Automatically option is ticked

Comment: @Gamb yeah that does seem to be the problem, I've tried refreshing, any ideas of how to solve this?

Comment: The workspace may be corrupt. I'd create a new workspace and import the projects at this point, to see if it makes a difference.

Comment: try running eclipse with the ' --clean ' option

Comment: As Andreas_D and RuntimeError suggest, I'd try to sort things out starting by the workspace. Also, did you try refreshing your projects? Closing them and opening them again?

Comment: I've ran the clean option and now when I run my class I get the following Error: Could not find or load main class Gui

Comment: @Andreas_D Creating a new project and importing all the classes across has worked. If you care to form an answer I will accept yours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Project was corrupt.

**Solution**

Copying classes across into a new project and deleting old project.

Answer (score 1):

When issues like this happen, the first thing to do is to click on Project -> Clean in the main menu.

Answer (score 0):

Try restarting eclipse. Perhaps it kept some content in the editor but the link was broken from the actual file that it's building. Maybe copy your code just in case the file is out of sync with the editor.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was the folder was in a different workspace, so the old version of my file was in there, but my newer saved version was in a different workspace. I didn't realize the newer version was somewhere else. This happened because I need to send files back and forth from my main computer to my laptop for school, then return the folder again. So be extra aware of your workspace locations! If you export a project from Eclipse, it will always choose one by default, but you can choose another in the export menu.